# Autoit SendMessage

Tags: autoit

I have this code to send mouse actions to an inactive window, but I don't know why it's not working, and it doesn't give any error. In this example I want to draw a line in Paint.

```
#include <SendMessage.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
Global $wHandle = "Untitled - Paint"
ControlClickDrag($wHandle,"left",300,300,100,80)

Func ControlClickDrag($wHandle, $Button="left", $X1="", $Y1="", $X2="", $Y2="")
   Local $MK_LBUTTON  = 0x0001
   Local $WM_LBUTTONDOWN  = 0x0201
   Local $WM_LBUTTONUP  = 0x0202
   Local $MK_RBUTTON  = 0x0002
   Local $WM_RBUTTONDOWN  = 0x0204
   Local $WM_RBUTTONUP  = 0x0205
   Local $WM_MOUSEMOVE  = 0x0200
   Local $i = 0
   Select
 Case $Button = "left"
$Button  = $MK_LBUTTON
$ButtonDown  = $WM_LBUTTONDOWN
$ButtonUp  = $WM_LBUTTONUP
 Case $Button = "right"
$Button  = $MK_RBUTTON
$ButtonDown  = $WM_RBUTTONDOWN
$ButtonUp  = $WM_RBUTTONUP
   EndSelect
   DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessage", "hwnd", $wHandle, "int", $ButtonDown, "int", $Button, "long", _MakeLong($X1, $Y1))
   DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessage", "hwnd", $wHandle, "int", $ButtonUp, "int", $Button, "long", _MakeLong($X2, $Y2))
EndFunc

Func _MakeLong($LoWord,$HiWord)
Return BitOR($HiWord * 0x10000, BitAND($LoWord, 0xFFFF))
EndFunc
```